# How to disable pop up when we click radio buttons or other elements in a table row using angular?

Tags: angular

I am working on a requirement where I need to display a detailed pop-up when I click each row of a table. But currently I am using the prime ng plugin for the pop-up. Currently, wherever I click on the particular row even on radio buttons with other functionality, this pop-up is being displayed.So i need to display the pop-up wherever I click on the row except for the radiobuttons or comment box (other functionalities).

*sample code*

**component.html**

```
<tr id="{{student.nameid}}" (click)="showhitdetailedview(student)">
```

**component.ts**

```
showhitdetailedview(student) {
    if (this.checked) {
      this.Hit_Detailview = true;
      this.studentid = student.studentid;
      this.studentname = student.studentname;
    }else {
      this.Hit_Detailview = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your html code here?

Comment: You can return if your checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Without your code its hard to guess..

One option is to hide it when they click on the button, modify it to whatever control you have. the `<p-dialog>` component has a `[(visible)]` attribute

---

**component.html** file

```html
<p-dialog  [(visible)]="showDialog">
    <button type="button" (click)="SomeEditButton()" label="Edit Me"></button>
</p-dialog>
```

---

**component.ts** file

```js
// Your Typescript file, 
// and make sure you have a ref of the modal and your can do modalRef.Hide() as well

export class StudentComponent {
  showDialog: boolean;

  SomeEditButton() {

    // closes/hides the dialog box
    this.showDialog = false; 

    // do your work
    ....
    
  }
}
```

---

Another way is to make it inline editing. which is default look at
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/edit